# Unable to use setSpacingAfter() and setSpacingBefore in iText java

Tags: java, itext

I've been developing a java swing GUI app that takes the input from user and write it on a pdf file.
 I am using iText library in my project.
I was in need to change the default spacing between two paragraph. So I wrote :-

```
paragraph.setSpacingAfter(floatValue);
```

But I was unable to do so as eclipse didn't gave a suggestion for method and further more gave an error :-

---

[image: Error Image]

---

Here cls is an object of Paragraph class.
I don't know where I am doing wrong. I tried both the of importing dependency jars i.e. adding external jars and converting my project to maven.
Please help me this is an important project.

Thanks in advance.

**Update :-**

Build Files :-

---

[image]

Comment: Which version of iText are you using. This method no longer exists in the current version; it was replaced by other methods. This method didn't exist in very old versions. From your screenshot, it's impossible to tell if you're using a version that is too new or too old for the method to be present.

Comment: I am updating my answer. I will attach the jar files that I am using.

Comment: Why aren't you using Maven?

Comment: I was but just to experiment things so that the method may work I switched to external jars.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: Your XML Worker version and iText version don't correspond. That's asking for problems. iText 5.4.0 is pretty old. Why would you start with such an old version if you're "just trying"? Show us the `import` statement that you use to import the `Paragraph` class. Throw away your current project and start anew with Maven. Consider using iText 7 instead of iText 5.

Comment: Can you give an alternative??

Comment: Yes, the alternative is to stop mixing iText 5 and iText 7, as you currently do. In your code I don't see you doing anything related to HTML to PDF, so you do not need XMLWorker. And if you really do need to convert HTML to PDF, then pdfHTML is the iText 7 compatible replacement for XMLWorker.

Comment: Will setSpacingAfter () method work in iText 7, or I should change to 5.4?

Comment: If you use iText 7, you need to use `setMarginBottom()` instead of `setSpacingAfter()`. iText 7 syntax looks very much like HTML syntax.

Comment: Ok I will try that. Make sure to add this as an answer so that I can accept it.